# Start method before starting specific batch job

Tags: spring-batch

So, I have several batch jobs. I want ensure that before specific one (lets call it A) starts, rest of them is stopped.

I wrote method that stops all of currently running batch jobs (including A if it's already processing).

Question is how to setup that method to run each time before batch job (A) starts?

Comment: is "batch job" here refers to job execution in Spring-Batch, or batch job of Windows?

Comment: You can annotate a method with `@BeforeStep` to have it run before the step

Comment: @AdrianShum it refers to job execution in Spring-Batch as I taged question.

Comment: @uncleMatuesz no you didn't tagged that.  Tags `spring` and `jobs` mean something different. There is a specific tag for `spring-batch`.  Lemme retag for you.

Comment: It have been long time I last used spring-batch.  However, I do remember JobOperator does provide methods for you to retrieve all jobs, to get all running executions for a specific job, and to stop a job execution.  What is the difficulties to have a step that get all jobs and for each job, get all running execution, and for every execution with ID different than current job execution, do a `stop()`?